# Please respond Mark!

Tags: cipher, visual, rebus

I have been trying to contact my son Mark for past 4 days, I hope he is alright. My 17 year old son went to attend "Mathematics Summer Camp", I am really eager to know about the camp, his friends, stories of his camp. Unfortunately, I am unable to contact him through his phone. I also received a letter from Mark, I don't really know what it means, I am really worried as if he's trying to say something through the letter.
[image]

*Can you figure out the letter from Mark?*

Hint 1:

> 11/7 = Pi/2

Comment: Is the last character on the man's face a `¿` or an `i`?

Comment: That last character is i. The number/alphabets in order are, 13, 19i, 2, 2, 11/7, 64, 32, 100, 19.7, in case of any confusion over the text

Comment: Does "i" refer to the square root of minus one?

Comment: rot13: BZT! Vzntvanel havg. Ybtnevguzvp shapgvba. Sybbe shapgvba. Ebbg shapgvba. Guvf vf gbb shaal.

Comment: @I'mNobody we need more hints... eish

Answer (score 2):

Very close to solving but can't figure out the last step. If someone wants to work off this feel free.

The Face Picture:

> No eye means remove the $i$ in some way.
>  We could just cut the $i$ out of the expression and get $19+13=32$, or we could cut out the $i$ term and get $19$. Or we could multiply by the conjugate $(13+19i)(13-19i)=530$
>  This pic probably means 32, 19 or 530.

> Edit 1: I read the problem wrong, thank you to @Galen to pointing this out.

> Cutting out the $i$ term means it would be 13, not 19. Before I read it as $19+13i$ instead of $13+19i$ hence the mistake.

The Log Picture:

> Log Base 2

> logb2(2)+ logb2(64) + logb2(32) = 1 + 6 + 5 = 12.
>  OR logb2(2) * logb2(64) * logb2(32) = 1 * 6 * 5 = 30.
>  OR, incorporating the 11/7, which is above 64, it could be:
>  11/7 * (logb2(2) + logb2(64)) + logb2(32) = 11 + 5 = 16.

> Edit 1: thank you @ribs2spare for pointing this out

> 11/7 is on a sign. So it means SINE(11/7). 22/7 is the common approximation for pi so $\sin(\frac{11}{7})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. So its basically 1 times the log stuff or 1 plus the log stuff so either 12 or 13.

The tree picture:

> The 100 is under roots, so root 100 = 10

The room picture:

> The floor function means round down. 19.7-->19

Combining them (or at least trying to):

> My first guess was this is some kind of convert numbers to letters cypher. Using the numbers 19, 16, 10, 19 gives SPJS. I tried rot## but didn't get anything interesting.
>  Now trying to round other options for the face picture: KPJS and GPJS
>  My next strategy is concatenating the numbers and doing base 26. These are my results: BSQDXWL, BPYESH, CSJVMH.
>  Multiplying instead of Concatenating. Results: DNRLG, FNXO, DHLO

> Edit 1: Alright now that I've cleared up some mistakes I'm gonna give this another go.
> ! The numbers are now 13, 12, 10, 19 --> MLJS or 13, 13, 10, 19 --> MMJS.

Still a bit lost.

Comment: The problem is not your last step, the numbers you have derived are not correct. You are definitely on the right track.

Comment: rot13(Gur snpg gung 11/7 vf ba n "fvta" yrnqf zr gb oryvrir gung fva bs 11/7 fubhyq or cneg bs guvf)

Comment: rot13: Gur "ab rlr" cneg zvtug zrna 'gnxr gur erny cneg'.

Comment: rot13: Be znlor "ab rlr" pbhyq or whfg gnxvat gur fhz bs 13+19=32, ohg zl vaghvgvba vf gung gur erny-cneg shapgvba vf zber yvxryl.

Comment: Rot13(Gurfr ner fbzr irel tbbq uvagf)

Comment: @ribs2spare Thank you for the help. I added ur contribution and put your name down to give credit.

Comment: @Galen Thank you for the help. I added ur contribution and put your name down to give credit.

Comment: @I'mNobody Thank you for the help. I'm still a bit lost at the last step. any chance of getting a hint?

Comment: @Ankit rot13(Lbh jvyy va gbgny erpvrir 7 ahzoref sebz gur cvpgher)

Comment: rot13(V guvax gur frira ahzoref ner whfg guvegrra, bar, bar, fvk, svir, gra naq avargrra, naq ol gur N1M26 pbeerfcbaqrapr guvf vf whfg na nantenz bs gur zrffntr.)

Comment: If the OP has made a mistake and the number beneath the tree should actually be 81, and you treat the three numbers on the log side separately rot13(gura guebhtu N1M26 gur zrffntr vf V NZ FNSR)

Comment: I think so too, Stiv

Comment: There is no mistake. The logic here is a bit obscure and @NumberBasher is just one statement away from checkmark. I agree putting 81 may have been better but rot13(Jung qb lbh ernyyl qb jvgu gur vzntvanel cneg (19v)? vg vf fgvyy n cneg bs chmmyr)

Comment: base64(Tm93IEkgdW5kZXJzdGFuZCB5b3Ugc3VidHJhY3QgdGhhdCBmcm9tIDEwMCBidXQgd2h5PyA) @I'mNobody

Comment: @I'mNobody Hello?

Comment: Why is the imaginary part even linked to the 100?

Answer (score 1):

## My answer, credit, @Ankit

The face:

> No `i` typically means the real part which is `13`

The log:

> log2 of `2`, `64`, and `32` are `1`, `6`, and `5`

The sign:

> Sine of `11/7` is `1`

The tree:

> `100` is under roots. We can infer that this is square root, yielding `10`

The floor:

> The floor of the decimal is `19`

We do **not**:

> Combine `1` `6` `5` from the log, because there are, quote, `7` numbers

Next step:

> We use A1Z26 to get MAFEAJS from `13` `1` `6` `5` `1` `10` `19`

Why this seems on the right track:

> There are three vowels out of the total of seven letters, which can make a decent word

However:

> There isn't any anagrams for it. It could've contain "SAFE", but it would've been "SAFE JAM"

Wait:

> What about differences? For instance, `13-1=12`. You get `12` `5` `1` `4` `9` `9` which is for `leadii`

Why this seems to be good:

> There seems to be still enough vowels and we have a double letter, useful for a caesar cipher

But:

> No useful stuff ocurr.

Going back:

> The sign is on the log, so maybe we apply log to 1? We get `0` mapping to `Z` (warping around)

So we get:

> `13` `1` `6` `5` `0` `10` `19` or MAFEZJS

This seems wrong because:

> We have too less vowels

Perhaps meaning:

> Caesar cipher

or

> Virgenere cipher

But:

> Both fail

I think:

> We still have a problem with the numbers

## Edit:

> Nobody ( :-) ) pointed out that the `SAFE JAM` should be `I AM SAFE`

So:

> The `10` is wrong and should be a `9`

So:

> The `root` was sort of a wrong interpretation

So:

> We have to link `100` to `9`

How?

> It could have been **`digit`** `root`, but I don't see why. Maybe later.

Comment: Rot13(Lbh'er irel pybfr gb gur nafjre, Qba'g lbh guvax "FNSR WNZ" jvyy orpbzr n zrnavatshy cuenfr nsgre lbh fjnc W jvgu V?)

Comment: Need some help.

Comment: Znlor fbzrguvat jvgu v.v.19 = -19 orvat nqqrq gb gur 100 tvivat 81. V qba'g xabj ubj gb whfgvsl gung jvgu gur cvpgher gubhtu. Fgnegf gb srry yvxr uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Ntr_bs_gur_pncgnva

Comment: Please give credit... I don't mind you working off my answer but please give credit because half of your answer was already in mine.

Comment: Oh OK @Ankit IHATE15CHAR

Comment: rot13(Tbg vg. Nsgre lbh erzbir 19v lbh jnag gb nqq vg onpx "haqre gur ebbg". Fb gung zrnaf nqqvat -19 gb 100 vafvqr gur fdhner ebbg fvta gb trg 81.)